# Programming WLS function excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to replicate a function for WLS (Weighted Least Squares) that I have found in a textbook in excel. There is a value error coming up and I think that I am doing something wrong in using the function.

The following is the VBA code for a supporting function Diag(w) and the function itself WLSregress():

```
Function Diag(W) As Variant
Dim n, i, j, k As Integer
Dim temp As Variant
n = W.Count
ReDim temp(n, n)
For i = 1 To n
    For j = 1 To n
        If j = i Then temp(i, j) = W(i) Else temp(i, j) = 0
    Next j
Next i
Diag = temp

End Function

Function WLSregress(y As Variant, X As Variant, W As Variant) As Variant
Wmat = Diag(W)
n = W.Count
Dim Xtrans, Xw, XwX, XwXinv, Xwy As Variant
Dim m1, m2, m3, m4 As Variant
Dim output() As Variant
Xtrans = Application.Tranpose(X)
Xw = Application.MMult(Xtrans, Wmat)
XwX = Application.MMult(Xw, X)
XwXinv = Application.MInverse(XwX)
Xwy = Application.MMult(Xw, y)
b = Application.MMult(XwXinv, Xwy)
k = Application.Count(b)
ReDim output(k) As Variant
    For bcnt = 1 To k
        output(bcnt) = b(bcnt, 1)
    Next bcnt
WLSregress = Application.Transpose(output)
End Function
```

This function should return the WLS estimator for the explanatory variables of equation being estimated. I understand the code leading up to the `k = Application.Count(b)` line but not too sure how the output bit is working.

If anyone could help me figure out why this isn't working I would be very grateful.

The following is an example image of the function trying to work.
[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Excel will start sizing its arrays with 0 if you don't indicate otherwise. For example,

`Redim arr(2,2)`

will actually give you a 3 x 3 array

```
      0       1       2
0    blank | blank | blank
1    blank | blank | blank
2    blank | blank | blank
```

Because of this, when you have `ReDim temp(n, n)`, you're actually creating an array with one more row and column than you actually want. In your example, you would expect the Dialog for A3:18 to be a 16 x 16 dialog, but it will actually create a 17 x 17 dialog, throwing off your matrix multiplications (i.e. `Application.MMult`)

Replace this line

`ReDim temp(n, n)`

With this line

`ReDim temp(1 to n, 1 to n)`

And you should now get results returned. Up to you to determine whether the result is accurate or not.

Comment: nice catch... however, it is still not working for some reason. I'll have to have another look.

Comment: Interesting; I tested it with your data sample and I was able to get results. Try changing all of the code from `Application.Transpose` to `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose`

Comment: Didn't seem to do anything..Could it be to do with how I am entering the function? I have entered it as a normal formula and as an array formula and didn't get any luck.

Comment: Working! Thank you so much. I think it was a combination of leaving out WorksheetFunction and the matrix multiplication.